# OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: python, docker, error-handling, airflow, psycopg2

Hi I am running a DAG in airflow and keep getting this error:

psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

I haven't changed anything in the script except for the IP address of the server I am connecting too a few days ago. The server has run fine since and have never come across this issue before. Could someone advise please?